# FancyBox [JQuery] Title

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How do I get the title of fancybox like with facebook, and / or as I put more words in the title of fancybox (fit so few)?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
        playSpeed       : 500,
        prevEffect      : 'none',
        nextEffect      : 'none',
        closeBtn        : false,
        loop            : false,
    afterShow: function() {
        $(".fancybox-title").wrapInner('<div />').show();

        $(".fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
            $(".fancybox-title").show();
        }, function() {
            $(".fancybox-title").hide();
        });
    },
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'over'
        }
    },
            buttons : {}

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

```
<a class="fancybox" href="images/01.jpg" data-caption="This is the caption" >Open fancybox</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
            beforeShow : function(){
                this.title =  $(this.element).data("caption");
            }
        });
    });
```